# How can I count number of floating points in a string, recognizing the floating point as one number? - Python

Tags: python

I have a string of numbers separated by space like this

```
test_string = '2.02.02.02.02.02.02.02.0'
```

when I do len(lest_string), it returns 24, meaning it is counting the decimal point and decimal places. How do I count the elements in the string such that 2.0 is counted as 1 element and not 3 elements?

Comment: How do you know it's 2.0, 2.0, ... and not 2.02, .0, ...?

Comment: "separated by space" - I don't see any spaces?

Comment: Your string is not matching your description of the string. Please provide a real representation of the string as it is in your code. Also, show the code you are using to try to get this count.

Comment: The number of `.` will be equal to the *number* of elements in the string, assuming you are not allowed to include bare integers. Unambiguously *identifying* those elements is impossible without further assumptions (for example, `"2.02"` could be `(2.0, 2)`, `(2, .02)`, or `(2.02,)` unless you have rules about integers or implied leading `0`s).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
test_string = '2.02.02.02.02.02.02.02.0' 

print test_string.count("2.0")
```

Output:

```
8
```

If spaces are provided in the test_string:

```
test_string = '2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0'

print len(test_string.split())
```

Comment: I think you should count occurrences of spaces, not 2.0. The example provided is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are actually separated by spaces you could do

```
test_string =  '2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0'
nums = [float(f) for f in test_string.split()]
how_many = len(nums)    # 8
```

Alternatively, if you are *certain* there is only ever exactly one space between numbers,

```
how_many = test_string.count(" ") + 1    # 8
```

or you could just

```
how_many = test_string.count(".")        # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `test_string` the numbers aren't separated by space. If they were, you could `split()` the `test_string` and get the length of the resulting list:

```
test_string = '2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0'
l = len(test_string.split())
print("Debug: l =", l)
```

Returns:

```
Debug: l = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`test_string = '2.02.02.02.02.02.02.02.0'`

or

`test_string = '2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0'`

```
count = len(re.findall(r'2.0', test_string))
```

output: 8